# How to switch referring to its state in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I wonder how can I switch display regarding to its state.

When I click start button,fetch will start.

I would like to show `isfetching..` while fetching which commented out original work below.

Are there any way to achieve this?

If there is some useful materials, please let me know.

Thanks

```js
var apikey="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple";
$(".start").on("click",function(){
  fetch(apikey)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <!--<h1>is fetching....</h1>-->
        <hr>
        <h2>Press the following button</h2>
    <!--<h2>Just a moment please</h2>-->
        
        <hr>
        
        <button type="button" class="start">Start</button>

        
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
var apikey="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple";
$(".start").on("click",function(){
  $("#isFetch, #justAMoment").fadeIn()
  fetch(apikey)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
       $("#isFetch, #justAMoment").fadeOut(() => console.log(json))
    });
});
```

```css
#isFetch, #justAMoment { display: none }



/* For snippet */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 3.5em !important; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h1 id="isFetch">is fetching....</h1>
        <hr>
        <h2>Press the following button</h2>
        <h2 id="justAMoment">Just a moment please</h2>
        
        <hr>
        
        <button type="button" class="start">Start</button>

        
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```